# Format logs for PyFlink application with different pattern for the Python part

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-flink, pyflink, pattern-layout

I have a Python application running in PyFlink.

Is there a way of saying *"Apply this pattern to the logs produced by the python code, and this other pattern to every other log?"*

I'd like to format the log messages that are coming from my Python code to show just the message printed by the app (what the Log4j [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) calls `%m%n`) but keep log messages printed by other Java classes that are not my code with some extra information (the logger's name that printed the message, the time... basically, this layout `%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n`)

I'd like the terminal to look something like:

```
2022-05-19 16:48:31,765 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.SinkFunction [] - Hello from Java

This line is python logging (no date, no priority info, no logname)...
```

I am using a ConsoleAppender for the root logger, and I could change the format in there to be just `%m%n`, and that works and it shows just the message in the "Python side"... BUT it'd also apply to the "Java side" as well. I mean: if I do that, I lose the Java extra information. It would look like:

```
Hello from Java

This line is python logging (no date, no priority info, no logname)...
```

<sup>Output from Java "bad" (no date, no logger name...), output from Python "good"</sup>

If I keep the root logger's pattern as `%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n`, my logs look like:

```
2022-05-19 16:48:31,765 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.SinkFunction [] - Hello from Java

2022-05-19 16:48:41,470 INFO  /app/borrajax/my_python_file.py:290  [] - This line is python logging (no date, no priority info, no logname)...
```

<sup>Output from Java "good", output from Python "bad" (extra information to the left)</sup>

This is my... current config file for log4j (unsuccessful, as many others):

```
appenders=borrajax_console,console

# This affects logging for both user code and Flink
rootLogger.level = INFO
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = ConsoleAppender

# Log all infos to the console
appender.console.name = ConsoleAppender
appender.console.type = CONSOLE
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern =%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n

# Console appender JUST FOR PYTHON:
appender.borrajax_console.name=BorrajaxConsoleAppender
appender.borrajax_console.type=CONSOLE
appender.borrajax_console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.borrajax_console.layout.pattern =%m%n

logger.app.name = org.apache.flink.streaming.api
logger.app.appenderRef.borrajax_console.ref = BorrajaxConsoleAppender
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set the root logger's pattern as `%m%n` and Java logger's pattern as `%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n`, e.g.

```
appenders=borrajax_console,console

# This affects logging for both user code and Flink
rootLogger.level = INFO
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = ConsoleAppender

# Log all infos to the console
appender.console.name = ConsoleAppender
appender.console.type = CONSOLE
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern =%m%n

# Console appender JUST FOR JAVA:
appender.borrajax_console.name=BorrajaxConsoleAppender
appender.borrajax_console.type=CONSOLE
appender.borrajax_console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.borrajax_console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n

logger.app.name = org.apache
logger.app.appenderRef.borrajax_console.ref = BorrajaxConsoleAppender
```